# Как добавить визуальный эффект при ajax обновлении данных к конкретной строке?

Tags: css, ajax

Допустим есть 5 строк:

```
<p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 1</a> <test>47534</test></p>
<p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 2</a> <test>4534</test></p>
<p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 3</a> <test>45364</test></p>
<p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 4</a> <test>4534</test></p>
<p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 5</a> <test>7373</test></p>
```

После Ajax запроса, 3 строка в файле ajax.php занимает позицию под номером 1, как визуально это оформить на сайте (вспышка строки или выделение цветом **на доли секунды** или стрелка вверх или вниз...), чтобы было заметно.
Необходимо что-то похожее на обновление на биржах.

**При смене позиции с 3 на 1, в строке изменяется параметр <test - цифры>**

Сам код:

```
<div id="app"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "ajax.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#app").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',1000);  
    });  
</script>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключаете например это https://animate.style/ и в функции `success` добавляете класс с анимацией нужному блоку

```
<div class="box">
  <p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 1</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 2</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 3</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 4</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://site.ru" target="_blank">test 5</a></p>
</div>

function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "ajax.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#app").html(html);
                $('.box').first().addClass('animate__animated animate__bounce')
            }  
        });  
    }  
  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',1000);  
    });
```

Comment: Т.е. в моем случае класс нужно добавить к строке, так `<p class="box">`?

Comment: Да, к строкам как я понял, не забудьте что если у вас не один элемент с одним классом, то это коллекция

Comment: Просто у меня эффект у всего списка строк появляется при каждом ajax обновлении даже есть класс прописать только p, он прописывается у всех p. Я не знаю заранее какая строка изменится, чтобы прописать ей класс.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: Теперь постоянный эффект у первой строки, если класс прописать для p. Если класс прописать для блока, то однократный эффект у всего блока при загрузке страницы. Буду дальше тестировать варианты. Видимо мне на стороне сервера нужно выявить изменения и прописывать класс конкретно для него, пока не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Добавил дополнительный текст test в строку по которой можно отследить изменение test и если он изменился, назначить класс. Но как отследить обновление test при ajax запросе не знаю.

Comment: Что вам с сервера вообще приходит, html?

Comment: Приходит список который у меня в самом начале вопроса, сейчас добавил тег `<test>47534</test>` цифры в нем если увеличиваются, то строка идет вверх. Нужно отловить параметр в `<test>` и задать ему `class="box"` если он увеличился. За раз может измениться несколько строк. Сейчас обновляю раз в секунду, получился бы нужный эффект.